# Unable to run node app using systemd

Tags: node.js, systemd

This going to be my first  node deployment. I have this app which runs fine on my Debian 9 server using this command:

```
cd /srv/myapp &&   NODE_ENV=production  yarn start
```

And print out this message:

```
yarn run v1.6.0
$ babel-node index.js
```

In order to demonize the app using systemd, I created  `/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Myapp

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/john/start.sh
Type=simple
User=john
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and in `start.sh` I have:

```
cd /srv/myapp &&   NODE_ENV=production  yarn start
```

Hoewever, when I run `systemctl start myapp` the node app does not start to listen on port 3000, as expected (`netstat -tulpn | grep :3000`
 returns no results)

```
# systemctl status myapp
● myapp.service - Myapp
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-05-13 06:14:04 EDT; 5s ago
  Process: 8852 ExecStart=/home/bob/start.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 8852 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

May 13 06:14:04 9606 systemd[1]: myapp.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 13 06:14:04 9606 systemd[1]: myapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 13 06:14:04 9606 systemd[1]: myapp.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling
May 13 06:14:04 9606 systemd[1]: Stopped myapp.
May 13 06:14:04 9606 systemd[1]: myapp.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 13 06:14:04 9606 systemd[1]: Failed to start myapp.
May 13 06:14:04 9606 systemd[1]: myapp.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 13 06:14:04 9606 systemd[1]: myapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have other variations on myapp.service but could not manage to run node.

What could be wrong here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Process: 8852 ExecStart=/home/bob/start.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
> ```

According to [`systemd.exec`(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#id-1.20.8), this means `systemd` could not execute the specified file:

> 203   EXIT_EXEC   The actual process execution failed (specifically, the execve(2) system call). Most likely this is caused by a missing or non-accessible executable file.

You should check if `/home/bob/start.sh` is executable and has correct shebang specified (that is, the first line of your script must be `#!/bin/bash`).