# Fail to start a process as a service? (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Tags: linux, redhat

I need to start the cassandra process as a service. To do that placed the following script inside the /etc/init.d directory as per the [doc](https://jansipke.nl/centos-cassandra-init-start-stop-script/)

so here is my script which I placed in init directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 99 01
# description: Cassandra

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

CASSANDRA_HOME=/home/cassandra/binaries/cassandra
CASSANDRA_BIN=$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cassandra
CASSANDRA_NODETOOL=$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/nodetool
CASSANDRA_LOG=$CASSANDRA_HOME/logs/cassandra.log
CASSANDRA_PID=$CASSANDRA_HOME/cassandra.pid
CASSANDRA_LOCK=$CASSANDRA_HOME/cassandra.lock
PROGRAM="cassandra"

if [ ! -f $CASSANDRA_BIN ]; then
  echo "File not found: $CASSANDRA_BIN"
  exit 1
fi

RETVAL=0

start() {
  if [ -f $CASSANDRA_PID ] && checkpid `cat $CASSANDRA_PID`; then
    echo "Cassandra is already running."
    exit 0
  fi
  echo -n $"Starting $PROGRAM: "
  $CASSANDRA_BIN -p $CASSANDRA_PID -R >> $CASSANDRA_LOG 2>&1
  sleep 60
  RETVAL=$?
  if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
    touch $CASSANDRA_LOCK
    echo_success
  else
    echo_failure
  fi
  echo
  return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
  if [ ! -f $CASSANDRA_PID ]; then
    echo "Cassandra is already stopped."
    exit 0
  fi
  echo -n $"Stopping $PROGRAM: "
#  $CASSANDRA_NODETOOL -h 127.0.0.1 decommission
  if kill `cat $CASSANDRA_PID`; then
    RETVAL=0
    rm -f $CASSANDRA_LOCK
    echo_success
  else
    RETVAL=1
    echo_failure
  fi
  echo
  [ $RETVAL = 0 ]
}

status_fn() {
  if [ -f $CASSANDRA_PID ] && checkpid `cat $CASSANDRA_PID`; then
    echo "Cassandra is running."
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Cassandra is stopped."
    exit 1
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  status)
    status_fn
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Usage: $PROGRAM {start|stop|restart|status}"
    RETVAL=3
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

However when execute the `service cassandra start` it ended up with an error as follows.

```
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]# service cassandra start
Starting cassandra (via systemctl):  Job for cassandra.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status cassandra.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]#
```

and

```
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]# systemctl status cassandra.service
● cassandra.service - SYSV: Cassandra
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-11-10 22:23:07 IST; 41s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2624 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Nov 10 22:23:07 casstestnode1 systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Cassandra...
Nov 10 22:23:07 casstestnode1 systemd[1]: cassandra.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Nov 10 22:23:07 casstestnode1 systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Cassandra.
Nov 10 22:23:07 casstestnode1 systemd[1]: Unit cassandra.service entered failed state.
Nov 10 22:23:07 casstestnode1 systemd[1]: cassandra.service failed.
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]#
```

I reboot the VM and retried again and still error is same. Any linux expert, Please help.

Additionally here is the output of the journalctl -xe

```
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]# journalctl -xe
-- Unit session-3153.scope has begun starting up.
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 systemd[1]: Started Session 3154 of user cassandra.
-- Subject: Unit session-3154.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-3154.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 systemd[1]: Starting Session 3154 of user cassandra.
-- Subject: Unit session-3154.scope has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-3154.scope has begun starting up.
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 CROND[24584]: (cassandra) CMD (. /home/cassandra/test/cr.sh)
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 CROND[24585]: (cassandra) CMD (date >> /home/cassandra/test/ll.txt)
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/pickup[23967]: A5210F1C27: uid=995 from=<cassandra>
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/cleanup[24090]: A5210F1C27: message-id=<20191111182501.A5210F1C27@casstestnode1.localdomain>
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/qmgr[2035]: A5210F1C27: from=<cassandra@casstestnode1.localdomain>, size=837, nrcpt=1 (queue activ
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/pickup[23967]: A8301F1C29: uid=995 from=<cassandra>
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/cleanup[24315]: A8301F1C29: message-id=<20191111182501.A8301F1C29@casstestnode1.localdomain>
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/qmgr[2035]: A8301F1C29: from=<cassandra@casstestnode1.localdomain>, size=845, nrcpt=1 (queue activ
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/local[24021]: A5210F1C27: to=<cassandra@casstestnode1.localdomain>, orig_to=<cassandra>, relay=loc
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/cleanup[24090]: A987AF1C2A: message-id=<20191111182501.A987AF1C2A@casstestnode1.localdomain>
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/qmgr[2035]: A987AF1C2A: from=<>, size=2878, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/bounce[24164]: A5210F1C27: sender non-delivery notification: A987AF1C2A
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/qmgr[2035]: A5210F1C27: removed
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/local[23698]: A8301F1C29: to=<cassandra@casstestnode1.localdomain>, orig_to=<cassandra>, relay=loc
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/cleanup[24315]: AA5AFF1C27: message-id=<20191111182501.AA5AFF1C27@casstestnode1.localdomain>
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/qmgr[2035]: AA5AFF1C27: from=<>, size=2886, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/bounce[24164]: A8301F1C29: sender non-delivery notification: AA5AFF1C27
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/qmgr[2035]: A8301F1C29: removed
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/local[24021]: A987AF1C2A: to=<cassandra@casstestnode1.localdomain>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delay
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/qmgr[2035]: A987AF1C2A: removed
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/local[23698]: AA5AFF1C27: to=<cassandra@casstestnode1.localdomain>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delay
Nov 11 23:55:01 casstestnode1 postfix/qmgr[2035]: AA5AFF1C27: removed
lines 1923-1959/1959 (END)
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]#
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]#
```

when I manually run the script

```
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]#
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]# ./cassandra start
Starting cassandra:                                        [  OK  ]
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]# ./cassandra status
Cassandra is running.
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]#
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]#
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]# service cassandra status
Cassandra is running.
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]# ./cassandra stop
Stopping cassandra:                                        [  OK  ]
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]#
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]# ./cassandra status
Cassandra is stopped.
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]# service cassandra status
Cassandra is stopped.
[root@casstestnode1 init.d]#
```

Comment: Those who down vote to my question please be kind enough to inform me what is the wrong with my question

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this question is hard to reproduce in my environment. you should try to read the log of cassandra, or check `journalctl -xe` as error message suggests.

Comment: I think this is common issue with custom scripts inside init.d directory. because I can execute the script manually as i expected with ./casssandra {start|status|stop}

Comment: @ymonad I added the `journalctl -xe` output also. I think there is no relation with cassandra, It seems this script cant execute the processes related . Please refer the last part of my commands. it shows that script is running perfectly when it runs manually. and there is no problem with `service cassandra status` command alos.

Comment: Remove all that init script and just create a systemctl service with `ExecStart = /home/cassandra/binaries/cassandra/bin/cassandra -R`

Comment: there is some thing to do . But I forgot that. this script perfectly working on another VM

Comment: I didn't tested but `chmod +x` might be help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50317418/3627572

Comment: You should not be using an init.d script, clearly you have systemd available and as such you should be writing a systemd unit to launch it. init.d support in systemd is for backwards compatibility only.

Comment: What does the cassandra log file say? It should be under `/home/cassandra/binaries/cassandra/logs/cassandra.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a answer from this [link](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7017128). The cause was there was a blank line at the beginning of my cassandra script before `#!/bin/bash` . Once I removed and then I executed below two commands and issue was fixed.

```
chkconfig --add cassandra

systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 3):

```
203 EXIT_EXEC   The actual process execution failed (specifically, the execve(2) system call). Most likely this is caused by a missing or non-accessible executable file
```

As per [systemd.exec man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

So root cause is

1. exact path is different not `/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra` - you can figure out using `find /etc -name cassandra`
2. file is not executable less likely as you can do it manually.

Comment: I can execute `/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra` also  manually. It is working perfectly. So what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is possible you are having an acute form of `copypasteitis`:

- init script was obtained from one location ("the internet")
- cassandra files are locateed in a different path than the init script assumes

your error claims:

```
Nov 10 22:23:07 casstestnode1 systemd[1]: cassandra.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
```

this `203` usually means some executable was not found upon `exec*()` system call
(i.e. exec was called with a non existing executable path)

Secondly, you are on `systemd` based distribution, so there is no need to use system V (old, obsolete) type init script

Let's see how to get you both on-board and up-to-date:

1. find yourself somebody else's supposedly working systemd unit file for cassandra (e.g. [this one](https://gist.github.com/s0undt3ch/969b744d3d7b88c29cba) )
2. open systemd documentation on a side: [redhat official systemd doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files)
3. put the unit file to the right location, edit it
4. after you've edited it, run `systemctl daemon-reload`
5. now try systemd-way to launch cassandra: `systemctl start cassandra`

So, after you have found why it shoots the error, please use thee 
now, for the error in the logs